# ffmpeg After adding watermark, video becomes blurred.how to fix it?

Tags: ffmpeg

```
Ffmpeg -i input.mp4-vf "movie= PIC. PNG [wm]; [in] [wm] overlay = 10:10 0 [out] "output. Mp4
```

After adding watermark, video becomes blurred.how to fix it ?

Comment: Set the output bitrate or crf

Comment: Show the log if you want more input. Not much to work with here. Why are you using `movie`? That's unnecessary for an overlay. Just do `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i pic.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" output`

Comment: @szatmary how can we set output bitrate or crf, please share any example. Thanks.